# setState() for stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to setState my buttonbar widget in the other file. What can i do?
-my code is true. I have any error. Just i want true setState.-
But if i write DesktopHeader.desktopHeaderKey.currentState!.setState({}), it's null returning.

```html
class DesktopHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  static GlobalKey<State> desktopHeaderKey = GlobalKey();
  const DesktopHeader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DesktopHeaderState createState() => _DesktopHeaderState();
}

class _DesktopHeaderState extends State<DesktopHeader> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return butonBar();
  }

  Widget butonBar() { ... }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting DesktopHeader, do you start it with key? In that:

```
DesktopHeader(key: DesktopHeader.desktopHeaderKey)
```

Comment: no just DesktopHeader()

Comment: I think this is the problem. try to start it like this

Answer (score 0):

you can try return type DesktopHeader class

```
 final GlobalKey< State<DesktopHeader>> 
     globalKey = GlobalKey< State<DesktopHeader>>();
```